# IE intercept URL

Tags: security, internet-explorer, bho, url-interception

I know [BHOs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb250436%28VS.85%29.aspx) are the way to listen to [browser events](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa752134%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), but the problem with BHOs is that it shows an [opt-in bar](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2010/09/17/add-ons-staying-in-control-of-your-browsing-experience.aspx) and this requires user intervention.

Are there any other ways of doing this without using BHOs ?

Answer (score 0):

What kind of browser events to you want to listen to? The subject of your question suggests you are interested in URL's. If this is the case, an alternative to BHO (for filtering urlmon calls) would be a Asynchronous Pluggable Protocol: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa767916(v=VS.85).aspx.